# iPhone 6 -random issue- callers can't hear me

Tags: iphone

Issues with volume .. Callers can't hear me. I can hear them when I cut on speaker. This is random.  Sometimes a reboot will help. May work several days and then go out again. Replaced sim are, factory reset, and still no luck.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, OS, etc. Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered. - From Review

Comment: Same problem here. When answering a call on iPhone 6s, I can hear the caller, but they can't hear me at all. Happens randomly as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too on iPhone 6 plus for a while - I don't necessarily have a solution, but I do have a process that's slightly less annoying than a factory reset.

When you reboot - I assume you are just switching off & back on? Apologies if this is already how you're rebooting, but just in case it's not:

Instead, try quitting all your apps, then press the home & power buttons at the same time & hold down for about 10 seconds - it will reboot, but it's a hard reboot, and I found that this got rid of the problem for longer than a regular off & on reset.

I've also found that it comes & goes with software updates, and haven't had it for a while. Fingers crossed that today's IOS 10 doesn't have the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Oh also - a few similar posts had some other suggestions:

- if you still have protective film on screen it may be interfering?
- it could be that Apple's noise cancellation feature is being glitchy. Disable in General > Accessibility.
- related to the noise cancellation feature: this is achieved with the tiny mic on the back between the camera & the flash. If disabling noise cancellation fixes the problem, the issue is likely with that mic. Blocking that up has been known to work, or if you'd rather not, head into apple to see if you can get the back of the phone replaced if still under warranty.
- if the problem happens again, play with the voice memos app - this will tell you if it's a mic issue, in which case getting the mic/charge port parts replaced may be the fix instead.

Good luck!